# Images loaded via Joomla Jumi module removed from DOM in Mobile Safari

Tags: joomla, jumi

I am using the Joomla Jumi module to call an external file script that loads via php a few images.

This in all desktop browsers, but on mobile safari the images are completely removed from the DOM.

I have tested just using the Jumi module to place an image with the "Code written" section of the module and it is removed as well.

Comment: Would you please be able to share some code from the external file that imports the images? It's very hard to tell what is happening here without seeing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing I think I have narrowed down the issue. For some reason it is only doing this on jailbroken devices.

Not sure why this is happening, but on any of my devices that are jailbroken the image gets removed, but on non-jailbroken it works just like the desktop browsers.